# Why can an interactive service create so many more window handles than a non-interactive one?

Tags: windows, delphi

I was doing some research on the amount of windows handles that an application can use. I'm using Delphi XE2 and using the AllocateHWnd routine which creates an invisible windows handle by using CreateWindowsEx for receiving and processing of windows messages.

I have found some interesing stuff and I would like to know from the experts why such behaviour.

When creating a service application I can reach up to 2220 handles on a Windows 7 machine, if I activate the option "Allow the service to interact with the desktop" in the service configuration I can reach about 9823 handles!

Windows 2008 runs the same way, I can create ~2220 handles on a non-interactive service and over 9000 on interactive service

I have tested on a Windows 2012 server and even with interactive service flag turned on I can't create over 2050 handles... Why such limitation and how could I increase it?

I know that a software that uses that much handles is a poorly designed one, but we are testing this for a software that has intensive TCP/IP connection processing which requires many handles to handle inbound and output TCP/IP connections

If my application is a regular desktop application then I can create over 9000 handles even on windows 2012, so, why such limitation on service applications?

Comment: I'm sorry, why are you using HWND with TCP/IP? They're completely unrelated? Really for large connection processing you want overlapped IO/IOCP or somesuch.

Comment: [Why is the limit of window handles per process 10,000?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/18/3926581.aspx)

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your program design. Windows really don't come into network communication.

Comment: Well we use assynchronous communication not synchronous, so I guess that for assynchronous TCP/IP communication handles are required in order to receive messages of when data has been received, connections has been established...

Comment: There's your problem. Use blocking sockets instead. Even with async sockets, do you really need 10,000 sockets?

Comment: Well, for using blocking sockets we would have to redesign everything and use threads everywhere...

I have found that the library that we use for TCP/IP use a pool for Handles, instead of createing a handle for each socket (for message processing) it rather share a single handle with many sockets..

But the main issue is not even with the handles from the sockets itsel, but I believe that we will have to restructure something beause we have many objects

Comment: Look at something like this, which uses IOCP - https://bitbucket.org/voipobjects/iocpengine

Comment: we have many objects that are managed by our application (cameras, this is a camera surveillance system), and its easy to reach over 200 cameras on a single server, I have analysed and found that each camera object is indirectly using over 5 handles (per instance of camera) because there are many control systems inside each camera object (for handling many stuff)

Comment: Yes but your software is flawed so a redesign is inevitable if you want it to work properly and stand up to a beating. Continuing down a bad path isn't a solution. You'll save yourself in the long run despite the work involved initially.

Comment: I don't see why a Windows service should create any window handles at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed. It shouldn't interact with any window in any shape or form IMHO.

Comment: Ok... I guess our error is to create too many handles per object (We have to use it for message processing), even if I change everything to blocking I would still have this excessive handle creation on the objects... I´m thinking in redesining the handle allocation system and instead of allocating many handles for the objects I can share the handles

Comment: @DavidHefferman How would you handle PostMessage and SendMessage without handle creation?

Comment: You can't. But there are other ways of messaging.

Comment: Hum maybe we could change the way we do messaging in our application, what other ways of messaging would you recommend? Basically there are some points in the code that I have to post a message to later it will be processed by main thread

Comment: That's fine. It only needs 1 handle.

Comment: Just a tidbit of information, our surveillance software is monitoring 10 cameras, recording, and displaying the images in ActiveX controls, and the entire system is using 568 total handles.

Comment: And to elaborate on my previous comment, that's a third-party software which came with the cameras, not our own in-house software.

Comment: @JerryDodge Jerry, thanks for the inputs... For that amount of cameras I doubt that I would have any issue with handles, but when we have 220 cameras on a server the things changes a little...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you face the "desktop heap exhaustion" syndrome.
An excellent explanation about it can be found on Ntdebugging's Blog:

- [Desktop Heap Overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx)
- [Desktop Heap, part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/07/05/desktop-heap-part-2.aspx)
- [Talkback video: Desktop Heap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/09/13/talkback-video-desktop-heap.aspx)
- [The default interactive desktop heap size has been increased on 32-bit Vista SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/03/20/the-default-interactive-desktop-heap-size-has-been-increased-on-32-bit-vista-sp1.aspx)

Anyway, as @DavidHeffernan said, it's better to redesign your app :)